# Can't change context.FillStyle color using If else?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, tetris

I am building a Tetris game and I am having trouble understanding why The following code doesn't work..

```
function createPeice(type) {
    if (type === "T"){
     context.fillStyle = "red";
        return [
            [0, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1],
            [0, 1, 0],
        ];
```

All my other pieces are blue via this code in my main matrix function...

```
context.fillStyle = "blue";
        context.fillRect(x + offset.x,
             y +offset.y, 1,1);
```

As you can see, I am trying to change the color of each piece depending on which piece is created. I expected this to work but for some reason it doesn't change the color ( but also doesn't break the program ).

One thing I looked into was the ability to use the original context.fillStyle = [ "red" , "blue", "yellow" ] to pick a randomized color from an array each time a piece dropped, but I was not successful.

Any advice on how to get this to work, and better yet, can someone explain to me why my if-else isn't working ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a little guesswork to this answer because you're potentially omitting other things that are happening between the `...fillStyle = "red";` and the `drawRect`, but:

It's not filled with red because you set the fill color to blue right before drawing. That's how the canvas 2D drawing context works--it's 'immediate.' The setting of `fillStyle` will take on many different values thoughout the program, but it's the value set during each drawing invocation that's used.

---

> context.fillStyle = [ "red" , "blue", "yellow" ] to pick a randomized color

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#dom-context-2d-fillstyle-dev
From the spec, the `fillStyle` attribute 'understands' strings of CSS colors and gradients and patterns. The idea of setting it to an array to have the renderer choose one at random, at this point, is pure imagination. I would say it's good that it failed--not to applaud lack of features and to spit on imagination, but to celebrate the platform having thorough documentation and specs that cover all the things implementors *did* bother to program.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided enough information to deduce why your program is not working as expected. When asking a question you need to provide enough information for us to reproduce the problem.

The second part of the question. Selecting a random item from an array is easy. The following function will do that.

```
function randomItem(array) {
    return array[Math.random() * array.length | 0];
}
```

Or for very long arrays

```
function randomItem(array) {
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}
```

Usage

```
const COLORS = ["#F00", "#0A0", "#00F"];  // Define once

const myColor = randomItem(COLORS);
```